# Google Function v2 : Archive not found in the storage location

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-console

The Source tab in my project's cloud console logged me this error message 'Archive not found in the storage location.' I prefer editing and testing the function in the console instead of the hassle of deploying from my computer's terminal.

I had not changed any configurations in the project and after a period of searching within the console, I found a fix.

1. At the top status bar in cloud console, regardless of which tab you're on, click the **EDIT** button. It will open up a page with 2 steppers.
   [image: Snapshot of cloud console]
2. Click the **Code** step, select your zip folder and click Deploy. This will restore/synchronize back the location of your folder in the project console.
   [image]